# using vector in c++ class definition

Tags: c++, vector

I have a mysterious problem. I keep getting a *‘vector’ does not name a type* error when trying to define a variable in the tour class. The library seems installed correctly, since I can define vectors in main. According to many posts here I have checked for the right vector includes and std namespace. Still I get the error.

main.cpp

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "tour.h"
using namespace std;

int main () {

        //vector declaration works here
return 0;
}
```

tour.h

```
#ifndef TOUR_H_
#define TOUR_H_

#include<vector>
using namespace std;

class tour
{
    public:
      //variables
      int teamID;
      vector<int> tourseq; //this is where the error occurs

      //functions
      tour(int);

};

#endif /* TOUR_H_ */
```

tour.cpp

```
#include<vector>
#include "tour.h"
using namespace std;

tour::tour(int id){
teamID = id;
}
```

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Doesn't look like real code. One tip, though: Stop using `using namespace`. Just say no.  I bet that your problems will go away in the process.

Comment: Use constructor initializer lists.

Comment: What do you mean no real code, I stripped it to the minimum relevant part as I thought was the best practice on this site?  Anyway, I did not use to have namespace std at first, added it according to a post I saw. Removing it does not fix the problem.

Comment: The problem is that your code doesn't seem to have seem to have anything that would give you the errors you claim to see, so could it be that you removed the problem in the stripping down process?

Comment: @dorien: Are you sure this code produces the error? It doesn't for me: http://ideone.com/wuLdnE

Comment: @dorien It isn't _the_ real code (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/38d18f89a6c7cbfb). It's "real" code, alright. Real includes, e.g. :)

Comment: BTW, concerning `using namespace std`, the post you want to read it [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: @Mike Seymous. Yes, strange he. Because I did it this way in my other projects. Starting to think it's an eclipse setup issue.

Comment: Could I be doing something wrong with the seperated files?

Comment: Thanks @sehe, didn't know that. Interesting post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing `using namespace std;` and `vector<int> tourseq;` consider writing `std::vector<int> tourseq;`.

You <s>probably</s> shouldn't put `using namespace std;` in your code anyway.

Comment: Sorry, this is good advice, but given the question it makes no sense as an answer.

Comment: I would remove the "probably" entirely, to make this even better advice.

Comment: Yeah, I tried everything. I did not have namespace there at the beginning, but did it because I read it somewhere. Removing it has no effect.

Comment: Thanks. I said "probably" because I figured there may be cases when it makes sense (even though I can't think of any except for dirty prototyping code - and even then I wouldn't use it)

Comment: @dorien, can you just pre-process the compilation unit? what compiler are you using?

Comment: Totally strange. I waited a while, did std:: and it started working. Bizar! But thanks very much!